# "Вступив под покровительство"? Именно - вступив?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, паронимы

> Кроме того, художники, как и другие ремесленники, объединялись в цехи,
>   что сродни были религиозным братствам. (Так, живописцы избрали своим
>   патроном св. Луку, по преданию – иконописца.) **Вступив под
>   покровительство** святого, всякий двенадцатилетний мальчишка (который
>   должен был уметь к тому времени читать и считать), уже навсегда
>   принадлежал этому сообществу. Цех принимал в обучение, воспитывал и
>   направлял всю дальнейшую его деятельность

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не скажу про святых, но Google.books находит множество цитат с "вступив под покровительство" в хороших книгах (большей частью по истории). Ниже два примера.

> Сумев объединить некоторые азербайджанские ханства, Фатали-хан изъявил
>   желание вступить под покровительство России ("Из истории вековой
>   дружбы", 1983).
>
> ...Но в силу складывавшихся в раннефеодальный период общественных
>   условий имел возможность сохранить в своих руках эту землю, лишь
>   вступив под покровительство сеньора ("Проблемы генезиса феодализма в
>   Западной Европе", А.Я. Гуревич, 1970).

Comment: А у меня вызывает сомнение сочетаемость приставки "в" с предлогом "под" - вероятно, советские историки просто избегали церковной риторики. Корпусная статистика бедна: по 2 случая **принял / стал под покровительство**, ни одного **вступил/вступить под** него.

Comment: @Alex_ander Если сомнения только в сочетаемости "вступить под", а не в контексте покровительства, то я могу привести множество цитат из самых известных книг. А придумать какой-то более объективный критерий для оценки мнений я не могу. Сомневаюсь, что в каких-то словарях прямым текстом указано на эту сочетаемость (не сочетаемость).

Answer (score 1):

Под покровительством находятся, **приняв** его или будучи *взятым под* него другим смертным.

Answer (score 1):

Художники, они же — живописцы, ремесленники, иконописцы. Предложу обойтись без живописцев.

Кроме того, молодые художники, как и другие ремесленники, объединялись в цехи, что сродни были религиозным братствам. (Так, они избрали своим патроном св. Луку, по преданию — иконописца.) Став под покровительство святого, всякий двенадцатилетний цеховик-богомаз, уже умеющий к этому возрасту читать и считать, навсегда должен был принадлежать этому сообществу. Цех принимал в обучение, воспитывал и направлял всю дальнейшую его деятельность